# Regex for any number above 20

Tags: visual-studio-2019

im using:
Dim Regex As Regex = New Regex("([A-z]{2})([2-9]{1})([1-9]{1})")

numbers such as 30 or 40 won't match, and if I change it to 0, then 20 will be accepted, which I don't want

Answer (score 0):

```
New Regex("^(([2-9]|(1[0-9]))[0-9]+)$")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex to select all above 20(21,22,.......):

```
/[2][1-9]/g
```